# POST unconventional JSON with emberjs

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to post JSON to an api through the ember framework, but my api JSON doesnt follow ember conventions. This is what I am trying to post:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary Kelly",
    "email": "mk@gmail.com",

    "subjects": ["1","2"]
  }
]
```

Ember expects this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 1
    "name": "Mary Kelly",
    "subjects": ["1", "2"],
          },

  "subjects": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "History"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Maths"
  }]
}
```

So, I need a custom serializer in order to make the post, and to do all other CRUD operations. This is what I have:

```
App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var subjects = payload.subjects,
        subjectIds = subjects.mapProperty('id');

    var p = {};
    p.user = payload;
    p.user.subjects = subjectIds;
    p.subjects = subjects;


    console.log('extractSingle', JSON.stringify(p));
    return this._super(store, type, p, id, requestType);
  },

  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    var p = { users: [], subjects: [] };
    for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
      var user = payload[i];
      var subjects = user.subjects,
          subjectIds = subjects.mapProperty('id');

      for (var j = 0; j < subjects.length; j++) {
        p.subjects.push(subjects[j]);
      }

      user.subjects = subjectIds;
      p.users.push(user);
    }

    return this._super(store, type, p, id, requestType);
  }

  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  }

});
```

`extractSingle` and `extractArray` work fine for get requests, but the serializeIntoHash function for posting isn't working for me- can anyone help?

Comment: Very interesting. I will follow closely this question. I myself ran in the same issue as you. What I did is adapt my backend (Symfony2) to ember. Didn't know enough at the time to adapt ember-data to my backend

Comment: @MichaelVilleneuve unfortunately adapting my API isn't an option :-(

Comment: yeah I understand. Not saying you should do it, actually it's a good thing you're trying something else. I'm sure you will help alot of people with this question in the futur.

Comment: Can you show the ED is posting, and what you're expecting (those look like the get responses above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm showing it as working, per the serialize hash you've implemented, extraxt* only run on get requests, serializeIntoHash is used for PUT/POST

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/58/edit